# use 'not like' in mySQL show statements

Tags: mysql, sql-like, database-schema, show-sql

I have a `dropdownlist` which is being populated by `column names` based on the table name selected by user in the previous `dropdown`. I am using the following query

`SHOW columns from abcTableName LIKE '%name'`  which works

I want all to include all the columns names except a few columns. Therefore , I want the query like this

```
SHOW columns from abcTable NOT LIKE ('%name','%pk','%fk')
```

which does not work . Even

```
SHOW columns from abcTable NOT LIKE '%name'
```

does not work

Currently I run two loops to fetch the columns names- `outer loop` to pass the table name and `inner loop` to pass the parameters to the query which takes a lot of time .I want to optimize it.

Can anyone please suggest ?

Comment: could you show your table structure so we can have a look to all the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a more formal method:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM information_schema.columns
WHERE 
    table_schema = '[database]' AND
    table_name = '[table_name]' AND
    COLUMN_NAME LIKE '%name' AND
    COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE '%pk' AND
    COLUMN_NAME NOT LIKE '%fk';
```

Comment: The first solution says `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL ` . The second one gives the following message `Operand should contain 1 column(s)`

Comment: @ALearner My code is untested, but you see above now should run for you.

Comment: Thanks .This would help too. I wish I could accept both the solutions as answer

Answer (score 0):

use where clause

```
SHOW columns from abcTable where field not like '%name'
```

look at Extensions to SHOW Statements
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/extended-show.html